# Keep rows with have a specific word

Tags: r

Using this command it keeps the rows which have the specific word

```
df[df$ID == "interesting", ]
```

If this word is exist in the row but it has more words around how is it possible to find if this word exist and keep the row.

Example input

```
data.frame(text = c("interesting", " I am interesting for this", "remove")
```

Expected output

```
data.frame(text = c("interesting", " I am interesting for this")
```

Comment: See `?grepl`. `df[grepl("interesting", df$text),]` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("interesting", " I am interesting for this", "remove"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Solution using base R. Indexing using `grepl`:

```
df[grepl("interesting", df$text), ]
```

This returns:

```
[1] "interesting"                " I am interesting for this"
```

## Edit 1

Change code so that it returns a `data.frame` and not a vector.

```
df[grep("interesting", df$text), , drop = FALSE]
```

This now returns:

```
                        text
1                interesting
2  I am interesting for this
```